# Rails - Stripe Subscription (Set Time Period)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I have stripe running great on my rails app and have 2 addidtional questions to wrap up some functionality.

1. Is there a way to create a subscription for only 6 months or any given set time so that a customer is not charged after said time period?
2. If a user cancels their plan entirely i need stripe to delete their subscription.  I am sure this is going to include `dependent: :destroy` but im not sure where to place it. thanks!!

Subscribe_controller.rb

```
def create

    token = params[:stripeToken]
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => current_user.email,
        :card  => token,
        plan: params[:id]
      )

      current_user.subscribed = true
      current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
      current_user.stripe_subscription_id = customer.subscriptions['data'][0].id
      current_user.plan_name = customer.subscriptions['data'][0].plan.name
      current_user.interval = customer.subscriptions['data'][0].plan.interval
      current_user.amount = customer.subscriptions['data'][0].plan.amount
      current_user.status = customer.subscriptions['data'][0].status
      current_user.stripe_plan_id = customer.subscriptions['data'][0].plan.id

      current_user.save
end

def destroy
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
    free_plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve('1')
    if current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
        customer.subscriptions.retrieve(current_user.stripe_subscription_id).delete
        current_user.update_attributes(stripe_plan_id: free_plan.id , plan_name: free_plan.name, amount: free_plan.amount , status: "Inactive" )
        current_user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your plan has been downgraded to #{current_user.plan_name}"
        redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
      else
        customer.subscriptions.retrieve(current_user.stripe_subscription_id).delete
        current_user.update_attributes(stripe_subscription_id: customer.subscriptions['data'][0].id)
        flash[:notice] = "Blah"
        redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    end
  end
```

Subscription Model

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User Model

```
has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

For Question #1) what you could do is create a process that can be triggered by a scheduler https://github.com/javan/whenever that then checks that a given subscription is older than 6 months and moved the account to another subscription

For Question #2) take a look at https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription.
You DO NOT WANT TO DELETE or DESTROY because you loose the history for accounting.

You want to update the subscription to a cancel status

Comment: wow! Looks amazing, Ill give it a shot! thanks! hope youre event is fun!